# Trouble retrieving app_data from signed_request in JavaScript

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm trying to get the contents of app_data in JavaScript, and haven't been able to get it working. I am able to retrieve and decode the signed_request as follows (the 'response' variable is passed from FB.getLoginStatus):

```
var sr=response.authResponse.signedRequest.split("."); 
sr_json=window.atob(sr[1]);
```

but sr_json always contains something like this:

```
{"algorithm":"HMAC-SHA256","code":"fb_auth_code_here","issued_at":1361914477,"user_id":"1234567"}
```

...no app_data.

Since all I need the signed_request for is retrieval of app_data parameters I'm not worried about checking the signature.

Any ideas? Is there some other place to look for app_data? Is it just not possible to retrieve it in JS? (and if not, I'd love to know why it's designed that way...) I've been playing with variations on this for hours with no luck. I'd prefer to avoid adding a server-side component to decode app_data, so I'm looking for a pure JS solution, if that's possible.

EDIT: I'm calling a URL like http://www.facebook.com/3rdWindowApps?sk=app_169352419879937&app_data={"t":"test123","a":"b"} , so I should be seeing {"t":"test123","a":"b"} as the contents of app_data.

Comment: What format is the URL you're calling your page tab app with? are you correctly including app_data in it?

Comment: sorry, should have included that. I'm calling a URL like: http://www.facebook.com/3rdWindowApps?sk=app_169352419879937&app_data={"t":"test123","a":"b"}